# Can't get return value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I don't know what the problem is. It keeps returning an empty array. That is, movieIds is always empty.

```
function getMoviesInCinema(theCinema){
    var cinema = theCinema;
    var query = new Parse.Query("showing");
    var movieIds = [];

    query.equalTo("cinema", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Cinema",
        objectId: cinema
    });
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        if(results.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                movieIds.push(results[i].get("movie"));
            }

        }
        else{
            console.log("Could be an error");
        }
    });
    return movieIds;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the query hasn't finished yet when you return from the function.  You should make your function take a callback instead:

```
function getMoviesInCinema(theCinema, callback){
    var cinema = theCinema;
    var query = new Parse.Query("showing");

    query.equalTo("cinema", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Cinema",
        objectId: cinema
    });
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        if(results.length > 0){
            callback(results);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Could be an error");
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it as such:

```
getMoviesInCinema(theCinema, function(movieIds) {

    console.log(movieIds);

});
```

Comment: I need the result of the query as a varable as such. var VariableName = resultofquery

Comment: @user3679294: You can't, at least not in a way that lets you usefully use the array immediately. Again, as James said, your function returns **before** the information is available.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `query.find()` runs *asynchronously*. That means your `getMoviesInCinema` function returns before `query.find` calls your `then` callback.

Because `query.find` is asynchronous, your function *cannot* return  the IDs directly. (It can return the array, but the array will be empty to start with.) Instead, it should also provide a Promise or allow for a callback.

Not sure what Promises lib you're using, so here's the option using a callback:

```
function getMoviesInCinema(theCinema, callback){
// Receive the callback --------------^
    var cinema = theCinema;
    var query = new Parse.Query("showing");
    var movieIds = [];

    query.equalTo("cinema", {
        __type: "Pointer",
        className: "Cinema",
        objectId: cinema
    });
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        if(results.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                movieIds.push(results[i].get("movie"));
            }

        }
        else{
            console.log("Could be an error");
        }
        if (callback) {             // <=====
            callback(movieIds);     // <===== Call it
        }                           // <=====
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
getMoviesInCinema(42, function(movieIds) {
    // Use movieIds here
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using

```
movieIds.push(results[i].get("movie"));
```

Try using

```
movieIds.add(results[i].get("movie"));
```

It might solve your problem.

Comment: can u try printing "results[i].get("movie")" ...

Comment: This is even more incorrect that the OP's original code and is unrelated to the actual issue. `.push` is the correct method for adding something to the end of an array (`[].add` does not exist).

Comment: and 1 more thing declare var movieIds in global scope ..

Comment: *"and 1 more thing declare var movieIds in global scope"* That's even worse advice than the answer.